# Can't stop multiple page (html) from overlapping divs using @media print css

Tags: css, knockout.js, overlapping, page-break

I've got a two-column, multi-page, data fed, phone directory. The screen layout works fine and the printing did until a recent update to DNN. I can't blame DNN because it might be browser related, but I have the same problem with Chrome & Edge. I've tried page-break-before and after and I'm ready to try a completely different approach. I'm looking for suggestions for a sure shot format, maybe a table layout, or grid, display? Also, is there a way to view css code while in print preview? This would be very helpful. Here's my @media print styling:

```
@media print {

        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        ul.leaders li:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 16px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted;
        }
        .pageContainer {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1440px;
        }
        .pageContent{
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-basis: 100%;
            flex: 1;
            page-break-after: always;
            clear: both;
        }
        .columnLeft {
            width: 50%;
            height: 1440px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        .columnRight {
            width: 50%;
            height: 1440px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .phDirRight{
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .phDirLeft{
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
        }
        .pageBreak {
            display: block; 
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
</style>
<!-- ko if: $root.selectedMode() === 'view phone' -->
<div class="pageContainer">
    <div class="pageContent">
        <div class="columnLeft" data-bind="foreach: $root.page1Leader">
            <div class="phWrap">
                <span class="phDirLeft" data-bind="text: dName"></span>
                <!-- ko if: dPhone -->
                    <span class="phDirRight" data-bind="text: dPhone"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div class="columnTxt" data-bind="foreach: children">
                <!-- ko if: cType == 2 -->
                    <ul class="leaders">
                        <li class="phType2"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                            <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->
                
                <!-- ko if: cType == 3 -->
                    <ul class=leaders>
                        <li class="phType3"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                            <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->
                
                <!-- ko if: cType == 4 -->
                    <ul class=leaders>
                        <li class="phType4"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                            <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko if: cType == 5 -->
                    <ul class=leaders>
                        <li class="phType5"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                        <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                            <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        
            <div><br /></div>
            <div data-bind="foreach: $root.page1Left">
                <div class="phWrap">
                    <span class="phDirLeft" data-bind="text: dName"></span>
                    <!-- ko if: dPhone -->
                        <span class="phDirRight" data-bind="text: dPhone"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <div class="columnTxt" data-bind="foreach: children">
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 2 -->
                        <ul class="leaders">
                            <li class="phType2"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 3 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType3"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 4 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType4"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <!-- ko if: cType == 5 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType5"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="columnRight">
            <div id="emergencyInfo">
                <ul class="leaders">
                    <li><span class="phType2">Emergency</span>
                        <span class="contactInfo" >911</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="emergencyInfo">(report accident, fire, serious illness, injury or crime in progress that requires immediate response &mdash; stay on phone line and give operator emergency location)</div><br />
            
                <ul class="leaders">
                    <li><span class="phType2">Saint Mary&apos;s College Security</span>
                        <span class="contactInfo" >284-5000</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="phType2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Problems with Utilities or Equipment</div>
                <ul class="leaders">
                    <li><span class="contactInfo" >8 a.m.-4:30 p.m., Monday-Friday</span>
                        <span class="contactInfo" >284-5657</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="phType2">&nbsp;&nbsp;All other times (including weekends and holidays)</div>
                <ul class="leaders">
                    <li><span class="contactInfo" >digital pager</span>
                        <span class="contactInfo" >236-8997</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div data-bind="foreach: $root.page1Right">
                <div class="phWrap">
                    <span class="phDirLeft" data-bind="text: dName"></span>
                    <!-- ko if: dPhone -->
                        <span class="phDirRight" data-bind="text: dPhone"></span>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <div class="columnTxt" data-bind="foreach: children">
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 2 -->
                        <ul class="leaders">
                            <li class="phType2"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 3 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType3"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                
                    <!-- ko if: cType == 4 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType4"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <!-- ko if: cType == 5 -->
                        <ul class=leaders>
                            <li class="phType5"><span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cName"></span>
                            <!-- ko if: cPhone -->
                                <span class="contactInfo" data-bind="text: cPhone"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" data-bind="text: $root.footer1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS alone won't help us. We need to see some HTML. Also, dev tools in Chrome and Firefox have a print styles preview button.

Comment: In Chrome: 3 dots (ellipses), more tools, Rendering, Emulate CSS media type (choose print) - Is this what you're taliking about? My layout appears fine using this, but the actual print preview does not. HTML: